# Ruby get array parameter from self in Array Class

Tags: ruby, self

```
describe Array do
 describe "#square" do
   it "does nothing to an empty array" do
      expect([].square).to eq([])
   end

   it "returns a new array containing the squares of each element" do
      expect([1,2,3].square).to eq([1,4,9])
   end
 end
end
```

In this code, I want to get the parameter '[1,2,3]'.

```
class Array
    def square
        self
    end
end
```

in the class Array, how can I get [1,2,3] using 'self'?

Comment: `self` already refers to the array object, your current code looks correct except for the fact that you don't square the elements of the array

Comment: `self`. The array is the instance you're dealing with.

Comment: oh I understand. thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning `self` as-is, unchanged, so that's how you're getting `[1,2,3]`. You've got what you need. What's next is to do something with it:

```
class Array
  def square
    map { |v| v ** 2 }
  end
end
```

The `map` method transforms one array into another. Here it's an implicit `self.map`.